# How to change the values of HTML form check boxes based on check or unchecked, then copying those values to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, copy, execcommand

This is my first post here! I'm a novice coder, at best, and I've been struggling with this problem. I want to take a multi-input form comprised mostly of check boxes, have the user, me, fill it out, and then click a "copy" button to copy the values to a clipboard. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to get all of the values or how to make checkbox values disappear if unchecked. I broke my code and I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

Can anyone help me figure this out and understand the error of my ways?

My current code: 
Ideally when the check box is unchecked, it will produce no value and the the other inputs will change based on selection/text input. 
When the button is pressed, the form data is copied to clipboard.

```js
function getVal() {
    var one = document.getElementById("form1").value;
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").innerHTML =form1; 
};

var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('#button');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML;
  copyTextarea.select(); 
  try {
   var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
   console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
 } catch (err) {
   console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
 }
});
```

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form id="form1">
   <input type="text" name="">
   <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Yes" checked="">Yes
  </form>
 <div>
  <button id="button" onclick="getVal()" >Copy</button>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `copyTextarea = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML` returns a string so when you try calling `copyTextarea.select();` it fails, not sure what you want to accomplish with that line though

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try jQuery then this is how I would do it. I am not sure how you want to format the form data so I will leave that up to you. Just format the Array how you want it. Good luck.

```js
var copyArray = new Array;
var copyTextareaBtn = $('#button');
  
copyTextareaBtn.on('click', function() {

  // empty the textarea first
  $("#hiddenDiv").empty();
  
  // reset array
  copyArray.length = 0;
  
  // go through each form input and push into the copyArray
  $("#form1 :input").each(function(){
  
   var input = $(this);
   var x = [input.attr("name"), input.val()];
   
   // **********************************************************************
   // if the input is a select, and the checkbox is check, 
   // add the option to the copy array, otherwise ignore the value.
   // I am jsut looking through the select and text inputs here so if you 
   // want a textarea etc you will need to add it to the first part of 
   // the if statement.
   // **********************************************************************
   if(input.is("input:text") || input.is("select")){
     if(input.is("select")){    
      if($("#form1").find("input[name='checkbox1']").is(":checked")){
        copyArray.push(x);
       }
     } else {
        copyArray.push(x);
     }
   }
   // **********************************************************************
   
   
  });
 
  // toggle the textarea to make visible for short time.
  $("#hiddenDiv").toggle();
  
  // copy data to text area
  $("#hiddenDiv").html(copyArray);
  
  // select text area value
  $("#hiddenDiv").select();

  var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
  
  // if can copy SUCCESS
  if(successful){
    console.log('Copying text command was successful');
  } else {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  
  // hide input again.
   $("#hiddenDiv").toggle();
    
});
```

```css
#hiddenDiv {  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="input1">
  <select name="select1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2"> Option 2</option>
   </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Yes" checked="">Yes
</form>
<div>
  <button id="button">Copy</button>
</div>
<textarea type="hidden" id="hiddenDiv"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is great! I'm more familiar to JavaScript, but I've been eyeing JQuery for a bit. It honestly seems a bit more straight forward. One question though, it looks like the checkbox value is still displayed whether the box is checked or not, is there a way to stop that in JQuery? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Sure, I added an if statement above to filter out if the checkbox is checked or not. I thought I added it the first time. Sorry about that. Good luck.